# How to use the api to import an Elsa workflows flow?

Tags: elsa-workflows

I want to generate a method that can import all the workflows that I have saved as a .json file and I can't find documentation on how to use the API to import, could someone provide me with the documentation or a curl to try with postman?

I tried with swagger but I don't know how to complete the different fields.